# No mantiene el dato al recargar la página

Tags: php, html

Dispongo de un **formulario para la búsqueda de unas reservas** con su información: fecha entrada, fecha salida, número de noches, número de personas, botón de **buscar**.

Cuando pulso el botón de **buscar**, me hace una consulta en la base de datos, y me muestra las reservas que están disponibles para poder alquilar/comprar.

El **problema** lo tengo cuando pulso el botón de "**Buscar**", que me mantiene los datos fecha de entrada, fecha de salida, pero no me mantiene número de noches ni número de personas.
¿A qué se debe?

**Muestro el código:**

```
function calculoNoches(){
    var check_in = document.getElementById("check_in").value;
    var check_out = document.getElementById("check_out").value;
    var f1 = moment(check_in);
    var f2 = moment(check_out);
    var noches = f2.diff(f1, "days");
    //Comprobación del número de noches.
    if(noches <= 0){
        document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "";
    }else if(noches == 1){
        document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "Estancia de una noche.";
    }else{
        document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "Estancia de "+noches+" noches.";
    }
}



<?php
include_once "Clases/BD.php";
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <title>Reservar</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilos_reservar.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.css">
        <script src="http://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/calculoNoches.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript"> 
            $(function() {
                var defaults = {
                    closeText: 'Cerrar', 
                    prevText: '<Anterior', 
                    nextText: 'Siguiente>', 
                    currentText: 'Hoy', 
                    monthNames: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'], 
                    monthNamesShort: ['Ene','Feb','Mar','Abr', 'May','Jun','Jul','Ago','Sep', 'Oct','Nov','Dic'], 
                    dayNames: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miércoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sábado'], 
                    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mié','Juv','Vie','Sáb'], 
                    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Mi','Ju','Vi','Sá'], 
                    weekHeader: 'Sm', 
                    dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd', 
                    firstDay: 1, 
                    isRTL: false, 
                    showMonthAfterYear: false, 
                    yearSuffix: '' 
                }; 

                $.datepicker.setDefaults(defaults); 

                $("#check_in").datepicker({
                    minDate: 0, //The value "0" means today (0 days from today). 
                    onSelect: function(dateStr) { 
                        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate'); //Día actual. 
                        if (minDate) { 
                            //Se comprueba si existe una fecha de salida.
                            var maxDate = $("#check_out").datepicker('getDate'); 
                            if (maxDate && minDate < maxDate) {} else { 
                                //Si existe una fecha de salida y es menor a la fecha de entrada.
                                minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate() + 1); 
                                //Se cambia la fecha al día siguiente del seleccionado en la fecha de entrada.
                                $('#check_out').datepicker('setDate', minDate). 
                                datepicker('option', 'minDate', minDate); //Día siguiente al actual en "check_out". 
                            } 
                        } 
                        $('#check_out').change(); //Activar el evento "onchange". 
                        $('#check_out').prop("disabled", false); //Se activa la fecha de salida.
                    } 
                }); 

                $('#check_out').datepicker().on("input click", function(e) { 
                    console.log("Fecha salida cambiada: ", e.target.value); 
                }); 
            });
        </script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="contenedor">
            <div class="busqueda">
                <form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" name="mibusqueda" id="mibusqueda" method="POST" class="form_buscar">
                    <h2>RESERVAR</h2>
                    <label for="check_in"><b>Entrada:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de entrada" name="check_in" id="check_in" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_in'])){ echo $_POST['check_in']; }?>">
                    <label for="check_out"><b>Salida:</b></label>
                    <input type="text" placeholder="Fecha de salida" name="check_out" id="check_out" onchange="calculoNoches();" value="<?php if(isset($_POST['check_out'])){ echo $_POST['check_out']; }?>" disabled>

                    <p id="calculoNoches"></p><br/>

                    <label for="personas"><b>Personas:</b></label>
                    <?php
                    echo "<select name='personas'>";
                    for($i=1; $i<11; $i++){
                        if($i==2){
                            echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";
                        }else{
                            echo "<option value='$i'>$i</option>";
                        }
                    }
                    echo "</select>";
                    ?>
                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="submit" value="Buscar" name="buscar" id="buscar"><br/>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>

            <div class="mostrar_cabanas">
                <?php
                //Si pulsamos el botón "buscar"...
                if(isset($_POST["buscar"]) && $_POST["check_in"]!="" && $_POST["check_out"]!=""){
                    $check_in = $_POST["check_in"];
                    $check_out = $_POST["check_out"];
                    //Llamamos al método "obtenerCabanasPorFecha" y le pasamos los parámetros del formulario.
                    $datos = BD::obtenerCabanasPorFecha($check_in, $check_out);
                    echo "el resto del codigo";
                    }
                }
                ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Mirar la imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Dices que *debería poner* `Estancia de ... noches`, sin embargo en el código no aparece por ningún lado que pongas eso, por lo tanto, no puede aparecer por arte de magia. En cuanto al número `2`, aparece porque tú le indicas al `select` que cuando `$i` sea igual a `2`, **marque esa opción como seleccionada**: `if($i==2){ echo "<option value='$i' selected='selected'>$i</option>";...` Por cierto, es una forma algo extraña de proceder, pero bueno...

Comment: Si debería ponerlo porque hago referencia al fichero "calculo_noches.js" el cual no añadí al código. Fallo mío. Ahora edito para añadir la función "js".

Comment: Debe de ser por el `SUBMIT` luego de recargar la pagina, le recomiendo usar `AJAX`

Comment: Ya, pero no pongas tanto código, pon lo esencial e indica dónde se encuentra el problema, porque si no hay que pasarse 10 ó 15 minutos analizando tu lógica. Ir al grano agilizará una posible respuesta.

Comment: @A.Cedano La opción de i=2 lo hago como la mayoría de reservas es para 2 personas, para "agilizar" la búsqueda, pero si el usuario cambia el número, deseo que se mantenga el que el usuario ha cambiado, no el =2

Comment: ¿Estás depurando el valor de la variable `noches` en tu Javascript? Parece que su valor es siempre `0`.

Comment: El valor de "noches" funciona debido a que ya hice la prueba con un alert() desde javascript. Cuando marco las opciones en el formulario, lo muestra perfectamente, y hace el cálculo de las personas y las noches perfecto, lo que ocurre que no mantiene los datos al pulsar en "Buscar".

Comment: No estés tan seguro, ponle algo aquí en la primera condición: `document.getElementById("calculoNoches").innerHTML = "****Algo para probar****";` a ver lo que pasa. Si no, lo único raro que veo es que el elemento tiene el mismo id que el nombre de la función, no sé si eso sea problema, se trata de dos cosas diferentes, pero uno nunca sabe. En cuanto al valor `2`, no actualizas el `select` en el `onChange`... Como ya comentó alguien, sería mejor que uses Ajax.

Comment: ¿Y para mantener el número del select que elija el usuario cuando pulse Buscar?

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71097/discussion-between-omaza1990-and-a-cedano).

Comment: Acabo de simplificar el código con lo estrictamente necesario... Ver edicción.

Comment: Deberías implementar una petición Ajax, que traiga los datos desde el servidor y en el `done` entonces actualizas los datos en pantalla.

Comment: ¡Pufff! Me resulta demasiado complejo, ¿un ejemplo para ver cómo sería?

Comment: ¿Alguna posible solución?